# How can implement Two-Phase commit with web application in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

I want to add Two-Phase commit functionality in my project.I search on Google about Two-Phase commit and understand the concept but not able to understand how can implement it.So please explain me how can implement it in my project or suggest me any link that explain the flow how to implement it.I have developed the project in ASP.NET using MVC web application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2PC ... between what? Two databases? a web service and a database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TransactionScope` class from System.Transactions assembly.

Basically you can define a transaction involving one or more resources (Databases, Transaction-aware WCF services, ...) and the framework will take care of the rest. This can mean doing nothing (i.e. the Database can handle the whole transaction) or promoting to a DTC Transaction if needed.

This is a good article explaining the TransactionScope

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope

```
try
{
    using (var db1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
    {
        // use the resource
    }

    using (var db2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString2))
    {
        // use the resource
    }

    // you can use other resources...

    // Don't forget this
    t.Complete();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the error. No need to rollback
}
}
```

Comment: Is it different then the Oracle two-phase commit mechanism or same because i want to implement same like it.Really i am totally confused.

Comment: Not an Oracle expert but I think it is the same. You don't have to implement it, it is the Transaction Coordinator job.

Comment: if we look at above example if i added one more server then i need to define one more connection string in app.config.Just look this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts004.htm#ADMIN12119 and let me know both are same.

Comment: Yes, they look the same

Comment: Thanks for your valuable replay.Can i start implementation with above code or is there any other way.

Comment: That will work. Remember that if you need a distributed transaction (more than one server involved) you need to make sure that the DTC service is running and setup on involved machine (follow the link in the answer).

Comment: I have started with above code but not able to open the sql connection with remote server.Is any setting required?